# how to add multiple link as scr in html

Tags: html

So I only know little bit of html and i want to add multiple link as scr in html page. Actually i am a streamer and i want to view all chat in one window, like youtube, twitch, and some other. So for that i have link to the chat like https://dashboard.twitch.tv/popout/u/xyz/stream-manager/chat and https://xyz.xyz/streamchat/xyz?transparent=false , there is one more. So i want all this link to be side by side displayed in one single window. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u071m.png). I hope there is some way to solve this problem. Also i know i can add stream chat with restream.io, but i dont want to use it.

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `iframe`.

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document (c.f. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)